# jQuery Fade In and Out

Tags: jquery, fade

How do I get jQuery to fade out the $("#recentTrack"), replace it's contents, and then fade it in again? The current code fades it out and keeps it hidden, rather than fading it in again:

```
    setInterval(
    function ()
    {
            $.getJSON('cache/lastfmCache.json', function(data){
            var x = data.recenttracks.track[0].artist["#text"];
            var y = $("#recentTrack").html();
            if(x != y) {
                $("#recentTrack").fadeOut('slow').html(x).fadeIn('slow)';
             }      
        $.get('update.php');    
    });
    }, 15000);
```

Comment: Do you know you have an error in fadeIn('slow)'; ? It should be fadeIn('slow');

Comment: `$("#recentTrack").fadeOut('slow').html(x).fadeIn('slow)';` isnt this giving you any error ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change `$("#recentTrack").fadeOut('slow').html(x).fadeIn('slow)';`

into:

```
$("#recentTrack").fadeOut('slow', function(){
  $(this).html(x).fadeIn("slow");
});
```

This way you wait for the event to complete.

Comment: @Te Riu If an answer has resolved your question, you can [mark it as accepted] by clicking the empty tick to the left of the answer.